# Preview not beign able to execute on 4.2 beta 5 - Compose version 1.0.0-beta01

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to get the device icon to launch the preview but I can't, I have restarted project, clean cache, make project, invalidate, build, clean, all the things but I can't get the preview icon to run my preview

Android version : Canary 4.2 beta 5
Compose version: 1.0.0-beta01

```
 //Allows to render composables with Preview
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-beta01"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating to : Android Studio 4.3 (Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 8)
https://developer.android.com/studio/preview

Other versions don't work well with Compose version 1.0.0-beta01.